# Cast ConstantDataArray to i8* in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

Simple question: "I have a ConstantDataArray of type `[7 x i8]`, how can I cast it to have the `i8*` type?"

**EDIT**
More Context:

The ConstantDataArray is created as follows:

`ConstantDataArray::getString(Fn->getContext(), "Hello", true);`

And I have created a LLVM:Function that has an argument with the type coming from `Type::getInt8PtrTy(getGlobalContext())` and I want to cast the array to this type, so I can pass it as an argument.

I'm developing a pass

Comment: Can you show a bit more context, like an example declaration, of the IR in you question?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Since your question is missing a lot of context, I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but maybe [`CreateGlobalStringPtr`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#ab81bf85457770dc76f2e536f201db219) would suit your needs?

Comment: @tuple_cat That looks promising, I'll give it a try

Comment: I agree with @tuple_cat, this should emit the correct `getelementptr` and cast to the string array.

Comment: It's working :), thanks guys, I spent so much time trying to find this. @tuple_cat do you want to add the answer so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IRBuilder`'s [`CreateGlobalStringPtr`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html#ab81bf85457770dc76f2e536f201db219) which is a convenience wrapper for creating a global string constant and returning an `i8*` pointing to its first character.